# Dependency inside a subcomponent not getting instantiated during unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I have a parent component with a child:

parent.ts

```
...
selector: 'parent'
```

parent.html

```
<child></child>
```

In both the parent and child I have a service that provides an observable that both are subscribed to:

parent.ts & child.ts

```
constructor(private service: Service){}
ngOnInit() {
    this.service.method()...
}
```

And finally, I have a unit test for the parent component:

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ParentComponent],
        imports: [
            ChildModule,
            ParentModule
        ],
        providers: [Service],
}).compileComponents();

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ParentComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

...

it('should create page properly', () => {
    component.prop = prop; // prop is defined elsewhere; not really relevant
    fixture.detectChanges(); // <-- failing here
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

I'm getting the error: `Cannot read property 'method' of undefined`. The stack trace refers to the service in the child component. And as I understand it, the error is from the instantiation of the child component. How would I provide the service to the child in this case?

Thanks

Comment: You have to or should mock the service in the `TestBed.configureTestingModule({`. Can you show this `TestBed.configureTestingModule({`?

Comment: I would imagine the service making it into your `ChildComponent` the way you have it. Can you try removing the `imports` (ChildModule, ParentModule) and adding `ChildComponent` to the `declarations` array?

Comment: I get the error `Type ChildComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: ChildModule and DynamicTestModule! Please consider moving ChildComponent to a higher module that imports ChildModule and DynamicTestModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes ChildComponent then import that NgModule in ChildModule and DynamicTestModule.` I'm not entirely sure if the suggestion here is something that I need to do.